# WiX bootstrapper in Visual Studio: Shortest way to rebuild everything?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, wix

In Visual studio, I have a C# solution with:

- several projects
- a WiX installer project
- a WiX bootstrapper project

When I right-click the bootstrapper project and select "Rebuild", it guess that everything gets rebuilt. But I am not sure.

Just to be sure, I sometimes do:

- Solution > Clean, Solution > Rebuild
- Clean and Rebuild for each project
- Clean and Rebuild for the installer
- Clean and Rebuild for the bootstrapper

Is it too much? Or is there still something that could be left uncleaned?

What is the best practice to be sure everything is rebuilt, while not losing time?

Comment: What are you trying to be sure about? Visual Studio has a pretty good system to figure out what needs to be built and/or rebuilt. Once you do a Clean at the solution level, it will clean all projects automatically, no need to then clean the other projects. When rebuilding, it rebuilds all dependent projects.

Comment: You mean that "Clean" is necessary and just "Rebuild" is not enough, right? Feel free to propose this as an answer.

Comment: I almost never do a Clean. Why do you feel that you need to?

Comment: If you are confident about this, it is an acceptable answer. I have become very suspicious after I discovered some bootstrappers contained out-of-date binaries, but I am willing to give it a second try.

Comment: It really depends on how you're referencing these files. If you're using the project reference options, then MsBuild will force the outputs to be rebuilt. If you're just pointing to the respective `/bin/debug/myadssembly.dll`, then MsBuild has no way to know that it needs to rebuild the related projects.

Comment: I have a dependency defined from bootstrapper to installer, but I know that if I don't rebuild the installer first manually, then it does not get rebuild, and an old installer is embedded in the new bootstrapper.